# Why was the “meta” key replaced on modern terminals?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I want to understand how the alt key behaves on terminals.

From some reading it appears that the "meta key" has been replaced on modern systems with sending Esc+ instead, why is that? What is the difference between meta and Esc+?

Is there a difference between what mac does vs what linux does when you hit the alt key?

Here is some discussion related to being unable to map the meta-modifier in vim because of what I'm pointing out here:

https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack/wiki/Linux-terminal-configurations-for-correct-meta-key-handling

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3412#issuecomment-174333178

Comment: Please post links where this is discussed by clicking [edit]

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key typically prefixes the sent symbol with the `Esc` character, e.g. pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> generates the `Esc` (`0x1B`) byte followed by `x`.

As far as I know, traditionally the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key used to set the high bit, e.g. <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> used to generate the byte `0xF8` (`x` = `0x78`; `0x78` + the 8th bit is `0xF8`). Or maybe there used to be two different popular configurations for the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key: setting the 8th bit, as well emitting an `Esc` prefix.

Then two things happened.

One is that today's computers no longer have a physical <kbd>Meta</kbd> key, so in terminal emulators running on PCs the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key took its role.

The other is that with the widespread adoption of Unicode (UTF-8), setting the high bit no longer makes any sense; in fact, conflicts with the encoding of pretty much any non-English letter. Applications expect the terminal to send valid UTF-8, and flipping the 8th bit would break this.

That's how terminals ended up with the current situation of <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or possibly <kbd>Option</kbd> on Mac) emitting an `Esc` prefix.